# Square - send digital receipt by API

Tags: square, square-connect

Is there a way to send a digital receipt to customer by API?
May be just download digital receipt template by API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround for this and just posted it in the developer forum:

1. The receipts are hosted at https://squareup.com/receipt/preview/{{tenderId}}.  To get the tenderId, after the charge request you'll receive a transaction response containing a transaction object with a tenders array.
2. Using the first tenders element you'll find the tender id.  Use the tender id to create the receipt link.
3. (Optional) Pass the link through a shortener like IsGood to conserve some characters.
4. To send the SMS we're using Trumpia (API is unruly and inconsistent, but they do answer your phone calls and will set you up with a short code the same day). Likewise, you could email the link.

Seems to work just fine as long as the receipt preview path doesn't change, which I wouldn't suspect it would.

Hope this can help some of you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll check it.

Comment: While this may be helpful for SMS it doesn't solve the problem that Square has created by ignoring the need to send a receipt by email when processing a payment using the API. We have clients who are on recurring billing and are used to seeing receipts and invoices formatted from Square. They get nervous when they get a receipt that looks different. Why won't Square add receipts to the API and solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are not currently any API calls to send digital receipts through Square. If you would like to send a receipt then you can pull the transaction data with the API and send it in an email.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Can you please show me API that pulls the template for the standard Square report?

Comment: There is not one.

Comment: As of Jan 2024 Square still has not added an API endpoint for sending receipts. They give no reasons for ignoring the requests, just that it doesn't exist. I'm not surprised that so many devs are leaving Square for Stripe.